# What should be remote URL if i want to push the code of submodule to repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules, gerrit

Here it goes:
What I am trying to do:
I have a project 'super'. I add a subproject from url 'ssh://..../prod/subproject' as a submodule using 'git submodule add ssh://../subproject'

There after ran:

```
super/>$git submodule init
super/>$git submodule update
```

Now i have added the submodule.
I add a file to subproject

```
subproject/>$ git add somefile.js
subproject/>$ git commit -m "add some file"
```

Now I want to push the code for submodule('SUBPROJECT') to the remote repo of 'SUPERPROJECT' without pushing changes to acutual remote of 'SUBPROJECT'

Basically, actual remote for 'subproject'('ssh://..../prod/subproject') is some important repo where if code pushed for reivew, sends a notification to a wider audience.

I dont want to do that, i want to push 'SUBPROJECT' code(with somefile.js) to my 'superproject' so that i can test somefile.js.

I want code in my local repo for submodule to be in the 'SUPERPROJECT' without pushing it to the remote of 'SUBPROJECT'.

Things i tried:

I tried adding a remote link which would push it to my repo as:

```
subproject/>$git add remote subproject ssh://../superproject/subproject
subproject/>$git push subproject HEAD:refs/for/master
```

But this fails when pushing as 'repo does not found'(I understand thats due to subproject is not a git repo on remote)

Then I tried pushing to subproject directly to remote of superproject, like

```
subproject/>$git add remote subproject ssh://../superproject
subproject/>$git push subproject HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Now, superproject is a repo, but it fails with error "No common ancestory".
I understand that this is because you cannot clone from one and push to another repo.

Also i tried to add the entire subproject folder and then push to super as a change where new files were added but it says:

```
[remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/dev/meta (database error)
```

Any inputs?
I am using gerrit- so I cant fork the project(AFAIK I dont know if there is a way to do that)
P.S. I am not sure if I am making any sense here. I have been digging up documentation for 2 days; but this is as far as I understand.

Any inputs, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may need to fork the original subproject and use your fork as a submodule. This way you can push local changes to your fork. Updating the submodule will require you to pull the changes to your fork before pulling it in to the submodule.

In your case you may either host your fork otside gerrit (if your policy do not prohibbits you from doing so) or create a new project in gerrit and import your clone.

Comment: :Just a little problem.. I am using Gerrit and AFAIK, i dont see a Fork option. Can we do that with Gerrit?

Comment: @RonakAgrawal, I have updated my answer. You may need to clone the submodule from upstream and push it to some location where you have write access and from where you can include it as a submodule.

Comment: Creating another repo is not something I can do. Can i do something with the existing repos?